# Is it okay to use a screw and a nut to connect minus wires from parallel circuits?

Tags: connector, ground, negative

I want to connect several 12 Volt sockets in parallel. On the positive side the wires are connected to a fuse box which is connected to the positive pole of a 12 Volt lead battery. How do I connect the negative wires? Is it okay to use ring terminals and put them on a single screw/nut?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your idea in principle. The implementation may be bad though. Could you add a photo, and also specify what current your fuses are for?

Comment: That works, but if you ever have to make changes it is a pain.  Probably better to use a dedicated distribution block.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev: I haven’t started the implementation yet. I plan to use 10 A fuses.

Comment: spade lugs might be easier to deal with if you have to make changes.  but of course they won't hold as well as ring terminals if the system is moving.

Comment: That is a fine way to do it. Just make sure you get a long enough screw ;)

Comment: I protest the deletion of my answer! It was definately a valid answer, as he asked if it was an okay thing to do, and I said, well you can read it above.

Answer (score 2):

You could, but really, that's what terminal/distribution strips/bus/bar/blocks are for. And it's easier than a single screw + multiple lugs.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

The last one is a car distribution/fuse box. Very convenient, especially with 10 Amp blade fuses being so common everywhere.